# How do I create a relationship between my Orders and Jobs table with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a database with an `Orders` table, and a `Jobs` table. There can be multiple Jobs associated with an Order. The relevant structure is:

```
Orders
- OrderId: Integer, Primary Key
- OrderName: String
- OrderStatus: Integer
```

```
Jobs:
- JobId: Integer, Primary Key
- JobName: String
- BatchId: Integer
- OrderId: Integer, Foreign Key Orders.OrderId
```

How can I use SQLMagic in Python to define the relationship between them and access the data from the Jobs object (with a WHERE clause to limit by `Orders.OrderStatus`)? I want to create a dictionary to return on my API like this:

```
{
    [Jobs.JobId]: {
        "OrderName": [Orders.OrderName],
        "JobName": [Jobs.JobName],
        "OrderId": [Jobs.OrderId],
        "BatchId": [Jobs.BatchId]
}
```

I have tried looking through several tutorials before posting this, and got to this stage:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from MyProject.db.base import Base

class Jobs(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Jobs'

    JobId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    JobName = Column(String)
    BatchId = Column(Integer)
    OrderId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Orders.OrderId'))
    OrderName = relationship("Orders", backref='Jobs')

    def __init__(self, JobName, BatchId, OrderId):
        self.JobName = JobName
        self.BatchId = BatchId
        self.OrderId = OrderId
```

The Orders object is:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer

from MyProject.db.base import Base

class Orders(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Orders'

    OrderId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    OrderName = Column(String)
    OrderStatus = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, OrderName, OrderStatus):
        self.OrderName = OrderName
        self.OrderStatus = OrderStatus
```

I'm sure it's something very simple I'm missing, but it's eluding me - I'm used to DBIx::Class in Perl.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem ?

Comment: @KarineBauch unfortunately not, currently I'm skipping the join and just working on the jobs table - not ideal! If you have any thoughts or questions, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been wrestling with this for a while, and got to the following state.
Jobs table:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from MyProject.db.base import Base
from MyProject.db.order import Order

class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Jobs'

    JobId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    JobName = Column(String)
    BatchId = Column(Integer)
    JobStatus = Column(Integer)
    OrderId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Orders.OrderId'))
    Order = relationship("Order", back_populates="Jobs")

    def __init__(self, JobName, BatchId, JobStatus, OrderId):
        self.JobName = JobName
        self.BatchId = BatchId
        self.JobStatus = JobStatus
        self.OrderId = OrderId
```

Orders table:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


from MyProject.db.base import Base

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Orders'

    OrderId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    OrderName = Column(String)
    OrderStatus = Column(Integer)
    Jobs = relationship("Job", back_populates="Order")

    def __init__(self, OrderName, OrderStatus):
        self.OrderName = OrderName
        self.OrderStatus = OrderStatus
```

It still wasn't working to access like the following after returning a resultset of the Jobs table:

```
result.update(
    {
        job_r.JobId: {
            "orderName": job_r.Order.OrderName,
            "JobName": job_r.JobName,
            "OrderId": job_r.OrderId,
            "BatchId": job_r.BatchId
        }
    }
)
```

It wasn't working because I was returning over 170k records. The amount of queries was far too many, as it seemed to be running an individual query per row rather than joining the tables as I expected.

So my latest solution does work, but I wouldn't recommend looping through a large resultset of data and trying to access a related table. I ran it with 300 records and it started working fine.